# How do I set a buffer in a possibly recursive procedure?

Tags: c, algorithm, memory-management, recursion

I just realized a major flaw in the program I was writing. It's a program that symbolically differentiates math functions, e.g. `"x^2+5"` --> `"2*x"`, and the master function involved starts off like

```
char * deriveFromTree ( node * rt )
{
    char * dfdx = malloc(100*sizeof(char)); // buffer
    if (rt->op) // if rt is of the form rt = gx op hx
    {
        char * dgdx = deriveFromTree(rt->gx); // g'(x)
        char * dhdx = deriveFromTree(rt->hx); // h'(x)
        char thisop = *rt->op;
        if (thisop == '+' || thisop == '-')
        {
            //   ADDITION/SUBTRACTION RULE:
            //   dfdx = dgdx + thisop + dhdx
            dfdx = strcat(dfdx, dgdx);
            dfdx = strcat(dfdx, charToString(thisop));
            dfdx = strcat(dfdx, dhdx);

        }
```

The problem, as you might already see, is that the result of `deriveFromTree` fits in a buffer of length `100`, but the result also be composed of several other results, which just won't work. An alternative solution is getting rid of the buffer and setting `dfdx` to be the exact length it needs to be:

```
char * deriveFromTree ( node * rt )
{
    char * dfdx;
    if (rt->op) // if rt is of the form rt = gx op hx
    {
        char * dgdx = deriveFromTree(rt->gx); // g'(x)
        char * dhdx = deriveFromTree(rt->hx); // h'(x)
        char thisop = *rt->op;
        if (thisop == '+' || thisop == '-')
        {
            //   ADDITION/SUBTRACTION RULE:
            //   dfdx = dgdx + thisop + dhdx
            dfdx = malloc(strlen(dgdx) + strlen(dhdx) + 2);
            dfdx = strcat(dfdx, dgdx);
            dfdx = strcat(dfdx, charToString(thisop));
            dfdx = strcat(dfdx, dhdx);

        }
```

But that is inefficient because of the calls `strlen(dgdx)` and `strlen(dhdx)` iterate through the strings `dgdx` and `dhdx` and then they are iterated through again in the `strcat` calls.

What is the best solution to this problem?

Comment: Please avoid tagging C++ unless your code is specifically written in C++. This is obviously pure C code.

Comment: use `std::string` and `+=`

Comment: Define a data structure - an abstraction - that represents expressions and stop working with strings altogether.

Comment: You have several problems beyond this. `malloc'd` memory content is initially content-indeterminate, as a such there is no known nulchar terminator. Thus `strcat` targeting said-buffer invokes undefined behavior. And of course, this also leaks memory like crazy.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have tagged the question as c++, I would suggest chuck char * and use std::string. 
The code would look like this:

```
string deriveFromTree ( node * rt )
{
    string dfdx // buffer
    if (rt->op) // if rt is of the form rt = gx op hx
    {
        string dgdx = deriveFromTree(rt->gx); // g'(x)
        string dhdx = deriveFromTree(rt->hx); // h'(x)
        char thisop = *rt->op;
        if (thisop == '+' || thisop == '-')
        {
            //   ADDITION/SUBTRACTION RULE:
            //   dfdx = dgdx + thisop + dhdx
            dfdx =  dfdx + dgdx + thisop + dhdx; //strcat(dfdx, dgdx);
        }
```

Comment: I tagged it as C++ because it is valid C++.

Comment: @MicrosoftOrangeBadge For example `char * dfdx = malloc(...` is perfectly valid C but not valid in C++.